Is using online interaction platforms like Wooclap effective in a university math classroom?
I'm considering integrating an online interaction platform, such as Wooclap, into my university math classroom. Previously, I would randomly select students to answer questions, but I noticed that this approach sometimes led other students to lose focus since they weren't directly involved. I’m hoping that using an interactive platform might engage more students by allowing everyone to participate simultaneously.
However, I’m also aware that incorporating electronic devices might be distracting for some students, leading to off-task behavior or screen fatigue.
Based on your experience, does the use of such platforms enhance student engagement and understanding, or does it introduce more distractions than benefits?

How many students do you have in class?

One course of 20 students. Another of 40.

I am not familiar with Wooclap, but it looks like a student response system (SRS) with various possibilities for types of questions posed.
There is plenty of research into student response systems, also in higher education and mathematics (or mathematical subjects) and plenty of best practices there; I recommend taking a look at that literature to get past some hurdles.
In general, these systems attempt solving two problems:

The teacher does not know what the students know. That is, the system provides a means of formative assessment.
There is more mathematics and thinking happening in the lecture hall when people are answering questions and maybe talking with each other than when they are (supposed to be) listening to a lecture.

With twenty students you can also easily have them work in groups, like about six or seven groups of three students, maybe on vertical black- or whiteboards if you have those, and they you can go around and see and listen what they are doing. This fulfills both goals one and two. this does take more time, so maybe combine with some kind of flipped classroom idea, where students are supposed to read stuff before coming to the contact teaching, or maybe introduce new ideas via group work instead of lecturing. After the small group work, have a full class discussion about the activity.
(Good practices with student response systems might be a good new question in and of itself.)
I have used an SRS also with about fifteen students, essentially as a form of formative assessment, but now I have mostly replaced it with group work. When teaching via Zoom I am considering a return to SRS, since there is friction from the group work, with some students sitting physically together and others not. Or maybe both; first an SRS, than group work, then another round of SRS and compare the solutions.
With forty students the group work might be possible if you have the infrastructure, but maybe not, if you are in an auditorium, for example. You might indeed have to use some SRS-type solution to do formative assessment and have students think.
Note that, as with any new thing you do when teaching, it will take a while to build up the competency and the classroom culture to actually use the new tool effectively.

I like Tommi's blackboard method.
There is also the solution of mini-whiteboards and "chinning".  Greg Ashman has talked about how they use this at Clarendon.  Essentially it is sort of like a "slate" that each kid has.  They work problems (or even parts of problems) and display the result back ("chinning") on command.
Of course the teacher can't in detail check every solution quickly.  But they can do a LOT by scanning.  And it sure creates incentive for every student to participate!
I apologize for not having a good link.  Have definitely read about it before (or maybe it was a YT video), but not finding it with a few searches.  I would think this sort of teaching is not just something at his school, but general.
FWIW, and in analogy, I have used electronic feedback systems for corporate presentations.  Voting and free response.  The software was Mentimeter:
https://www.mentimeter.com/ (not promotional, just fyi.)
Attendees raved about how they liked it better to have some interaction (even just before and after) versus death by Powerpoint.  So, I could see how a class electronic system might be appreciated also.  (Just sharing Mentimeter as an analogy for driving participation--it's not exactly suitable for your problem).
One caution I would have about an electronic system is that there is a secondary hurdle of using some equation editor or even just typing.  And don't wave this away, if you are good at it.  Not everyone likes code or pseudocode.  (Wikicode is a significant hurdle to casual participation.  And I personally despise Latex or people who expect me to learn it.)  And not everyone is a speed, accurate typist.  So, I think writing on class boards, miniboards (slates), or even just paper in class is a better way to drive real participation.
(But I've never used the specific software, you mentioned.  Just sharing a half a loaf in case it helps!)
